# avahi dns doesn't work

Tags: avahi, mdns

I'm trying to get dns resolution of Avahi .local domains.

I can do:

```
$ avahi-resolve-host-name redacted.local
Redacted.local  10.xx.xx.xx
```

but not

```
ping redacted.local
ping: redacted.local: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your machine is not configured to actually use Avahi to do (or assist) it's DNS lookups. Try adding the following to the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

The IP address might be different in your case, make sure that it points to the server running Avahi. Then reload your resolve configuration by running:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

The system should now (also) check your Avahi server to resolve `redacted.local` into an IP address.

Comment: I'm running out of the box ubuntu 16.10. I don't know what my nameserver is

Comment: If you installed Avahi on the same machine from which you're trying to resolve the domain name, `127.0.0.1` should work.

Comment: As I said, I didn't install Avahi. It's supposed to be pre-installed and pre-configured.

Comment: Where did you say that? You just said your using "out of the box ubuntu 16.10". And no, it's not supposed to be pre-installed and pre-configured on a new install. Somewhere, someone installed Avahi, but apparently did not take the time to configure it in such a way that the server uses Avahi's DNS zones for lookups. But try the steps I mentioned in my answer, it should get your lookups working.

Comment: avahi-resolve-host-name is definitely pre-installed

Comment: Wheter or not it is is besides the point, Did you make the changes to the resolv.conf base file and how did that work out?

Comment: I already have mdns4_minimal in my /etc/nsswitch.conf this should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Looks like a known issue with libnss-resolve/systemd-resolved and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  Check out this other answer on Ask Ubuntu:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/838395

Some other reading with alternate options for `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340042&p=13557382#post13557382
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1641328

Comment: Thanks for contributing :) A couple of general points... If your answer is essentially a referral to another post on Ask Ubuntu, consider flagging the question as a duplicate instead. If you are posting links, please include the key information here. Answers should be complete in themselves as far as possible.