# What's the policy on commenting changes/value in configuration files at upgrades?

Tags: configuration

Is there a policy for Ubuntu developers/package maintainers about commenting changes to values in configuration files? I'm asking because the upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 apparently changed `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to include

```
hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

instead of

```
hosts:          files dns
```

and I have no idea what that means - and it would be KISS to have a comment right in the file. The change might have other reasons, but for the sake of the question lets assume it was changed by the update (if someone has a better example I'll edit the question).

I'm asking because I'm configuring my system with a system of templates which diff the result of variable substitution/the output of the template with the currently existing file and enforce confirmation so I have a change to incorporate changes to default values into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by a bug as noted [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624071)  and [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837982/how-to-configure-local-dns-lookup-in-ubuntu-16-10)

In answer to your specific question, I don't personally know about any specific policies regarding commenting changes to values in configuration files but I would assume that you could ask that question of the package maintainers [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd) and likely receive an accurate response as it's more in their realm than ours.